# how to use "order by" and "count()" in one select query

Tags: android, count, android-contentresolver, mediastore

There is a table named images in mediastore database in android, the images table has a column named timetaken which represents created time of the image, and it is in milliseconds unit.

Now I have a demand that I want to group the images by created day(not the time), and count images of each day, so I have try this query:

SELECT datetaken/86400000*86400000 as dateT, count(dateT) as imageSumInDate 
FROM images 
WHERE (1 = 1 ) 
group by (dateT) 
ORDER BY dateT DESC

Unfortunately, it comes out a error:

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: dateT (code 1)

Then I ask someone else for the problem, and he give a sub-query style like this below:

select dateT,COUNT(dateT) as imageSumInDate
from (SELECT datetaken/86400000*86400000 as dateT FROM images)t
WHERE (1 = 1 ) 
group by (dateT) 
ORDER BY dateT DESC

This may be correct, but I can't use this sub-query in ContentResolver's query method. ContentResolver may only support the query like this style:

```
select ____ from table where ______ order by____
```

Is there any trick to help me fit the ContentResolver's query style?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT datetaken/86400000*86400000 as dateT, count(datetaken) as imageSumInDate FROM images WHERE (1 = 1 ) GROUP BY (datetaken/86400000*86400000) ORDER BY datetaken/86400000*86400000 DESC
```

The issue is that the `dateT` column alias is not valid in the scope of the `ORDER BY` clause. Simply repeating the `dateT` expression rather than using the `dateT` alias should solve the problem.

**EDIT**: Removed all references to `dateT` column alias from query. (Which clearly I should have done to start. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but it still comes out the same error:no such column: dateT, it seems that the dateT column alias is not valid in the scope of the count function.If I delete "count(dateT) as imageSumInDate",it will be execute correctly

Comment: Ah. The issue was the `count()` expression or the `group by` clause, then, and not (only) the `order by`. I've updated my answer; please try that.

Comment: I have tried all your three answers,all come out to the same error.If I delete "count(dateT) as imageSumInDate", and use "SELECT datetaken/86400000*86400000 as dateT FROM images WHERE (1 = 1 ) group by (dateT) ORDER BY dateT DESC",it will run correctly.It seems that there are some problems in the scope of the "count()" with alias.

Comment: The query currently in my answer -- `SELECT datetaken/86400000*86400000 as dateT, count(datetaken) as imageSumInDate FROM images WHERE (1 = 1) GROUP BY (datetaken/86400000*86400000) ORDER BY datetaken/86400000*86400000 DESC` -- really ought not to raise any errors about `dateT` because it does not reference `dateT` anywhere in the query (except to define it, obviously). Are you sure that executing that query is raising an error about `dateT`?

Comment: Yeah,I am sure.The logcat just say:<code>06-27 11:10:16.480: W/System.err(13417): 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 
no such column: dateT (code 1): , while compiling: 

SELECT datetaken/86400000*86400000 as dateT, count(dateT) as imageSumInDate FROM images 

WHERE (1 = 1 ) group by (datetaken/86400000*86400000) ORDER BY 

datetaken/86400000*86400000 DESC</code>

Comment: Ah. Please check the query in my post and comment. The query you're running is not the same query that I'm posting: `SELECT datetaken/86400000*86400000 as dateT, count(datetaken) as imageSumInDate FROM images WHERE (1 = 1) GROUP BY (datetaken/86400000*86400000) ORDER BY datetaken/86400000*86400000 DESC`

Comment: I'm very sorry to miss that.It runs OK,but it groups images by created time,not the created day.I make the "datetaken/86400000*86400000"(86400000=1000*60*60*24) in order to cut the millseconds of time to millseconds of day.

Comment: Happy to help. <shameless-plug>It's customary to upvote or accept answers that are helpful. :)</shameless-plug>

Answer (score 0):

It is also solved by a trick to fit the ContentResolver's query style:

**select** dateT,COUNT(dateT) as imageSumInDate
from (SELECT datetaken/86400000*86400000 as dateT **FROM images where** (1=1))t
group by (dateT) 
**ORDER BY** dateT DESC